# NvAPI on Kepler 20 card

Tags: performance, nvidia, nvapi

I'm trying to use NVAPI to get GPU information. 
But NvAPI fails to return the data on K20c with NVIDIA_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND

I'm using Windows Server 2012 & the display is driven by Onboard chip.
Is NvApi supported on K20 cards?
Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is due to the wrong driver being loaded (`nouveau` instead of `nvidia` - you can check it with `lsmod`). Other option is to download and install up-to-date drivers from NVidia.

The command `nvidia-smi` should work at least and report GPU information.

Comment: I'm using Windows so checked under Device Manager -> Driver File Details, napi64.dll is coming from Nvidia Corporation. So, dll from nouveau  is ruled out. However, the display is driven by Onboard chip. Could this be a reason ?

Comment: oh yes - better you add in your question we are speaking of a windows system. So are you dealing with a windows system with a non-nvidia display card and the K20c as a second compute card, isn't it? Better you specify as well in the question - My help stops here in this case - I have successfully used similar configurations with Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

K20c cards are supported by NVML interface provided Nvidia
https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml

This Library provides the monitoring & managing information.